# If $y+\frac{1}{y}=5$, find in the simplest form the values of $y^3+\frac{1}{y^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

If $y+\frac{1}{y}=5$, find in the simplest form the values of $y^3+\frac{1}{y^3}$

So I wrote:

$$y+\frac{1}{y}=5$$

with a common denominator which is:

$$\frac{y^2+1}{y}=5$$

Multiply $y$ to the other side and got:

$$y^2+1=5y$$

then i moved $5y$ and got

$$y^2+5y+1=0$$

but wouldnt that mean $y$ would have two values? Does anyone understand this problem?

Comment: Hint;  square your expression to see $y^2+\frac 1{y^2}=23$  Keep going from there.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $(y+\frac{1}{y})^3=y^3+\frac{1}{y^3}+3y\frac{1}{y}(y+\frac{1}{y})$.

Answer (score 2):

Squaring you get
$$y^2+2+\frac{1}{y^2}=25$$

Thus 
$$y^2+\frac{1}{y^2}=23$$

Thus
$$(y^2+\frac{1}{y^2})(y+\frac{1}{y})=23 \cdot 5$$

Do the multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint***: Use the formula $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$$. Find $a^2+b^2$ as mentioned in the comment